# Setting the facets on AlgoliaSearchHelper after calling the setIndex to change the index

Tags: javascript, algolia

I have several different indices that I am toggling between each of which have different facets. I have successfully used the `setIndex` method on the  `AlgoliaSearchHelper` instance but need to change the facets.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please edit your post with your so we may better help you, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using Algolia Helper using JavaScript to toggle between indices and dynamically loading the facets.